# Performance compare, get concat string by subquery or join table?

Tags: mysql

I have a query need to get more then one field from another table, which one of the following will be faster?

1
`SELECT *, (SELECT CONCAT(fieldA,'|',fieldB) FROM tableB WHERE bid=id) as moreField FROM tableA`

2
`SELECT tableA.*, tableB.fieldA, tableB.fieldB FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON bid=id`

Actually, I need fieldA and fieldB as separated values, so in case one I will use explode('|',moreField) in PHP to get them separated after the query. Just want to know which query will be faster.

Comment: Have you tried to run them to see which one is faster at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about performance comparison are too broad and can easily be made by the person asking, with a little effort.

Comment: #2 is the canonical way to do it, is it actually causing a problem?   Unlike #1 it will not return null if either column is null

Comment: Performance aside, #1 is hideous and will slow you down, both with the extra logic now and debugging/maintenance/extension tasks in the future.MySQL would be a bit of a shambles if somehow #1 optimised better than #2, but as @PhiterFernandes suggests you could try this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, nested queries are slow.

If you need concatened results You could do :

```
SELECT tableA.*, tableB.fieldA, tableB.fieldB, CONCAT(tableB.fieldA,'|',tableB.fieldB) as moreField 
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON bid=id
```

But you say that you actually need separated values so just use your second solution.